# Does not using a decorator in pyglet cause problems?

Tags: python, pyglet

I was making a simple code in pyglet to draw a rectangle on the screen but when i used the proper code format, nothing happens but no errors are thrown up either

```py
window=pyglet.window.Window()
rect=pyglet.shapes.Shapes(0,0,50,50,color=(255,255,255))
@window.event
def draw_():
    rect.draw()
pyglet.app.run()
```

this code just results in a black screen. The rectangle is not printed but if i use this code instead

```py
window=pyglet.window.Window()
rect=pyglet.shapes.Shapes(0,0,50,50,color=(255,255,255))
    
def draw_():
    rect.draw()
pyglet.app.run()
```

the rectangle is printed.
As the 2nd code is not the standard method of drawing a shape in pyglet, i wanted to know if there is anything wrong with doing that(performance issues, glitches etc)
If the 2nd code is wrong, what should i do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redraw event is [`on_draw()`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/window.html#pyglet.window.Window.on_draw) rather than `draw_`:

```py
@window.event
def on_draw():
    rect.draw()
```

---

If you don't use a decorator, the default event handler is completely replaced:

> ```py
> def on_draw():
>    rect.draw()
> ```

When you use the decoration, an additional event handler is added. Therefore the default handler is kept:

> ```py
> @window.event
> def on_draw():
>    rect.draw()
> ```

See [PyGlet - Setting event handlers](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/events.html#setting-event-handlers)

> [...] The simplest way is to directly attach the event handler to the corresponding attribute on the object. This will completely replace the default event handler. [...]
>
> [...] If you don’t want to replace the default event handler, but instead want to add an additional one, pyglet provides a shortcut using the event decorator. Your custom event handler will run, followed by the default event handler. [...]